# Duplicated output from script that runs with on edit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet populated via a web form. In it I have the sheets: `"Members Registration"` and `"sheet18"`.

In form submissions, `Column B` is populated with names and `column E` is populated with emails. `Column G` remains empty until it's manually updated with different texts.

[image]
I need to copy the values of the last row, only `column B and E` from `"Members Registration"` to the last empty row in `"sheet18"` **BUT ONLY IF** the text "`Not Found`" is typed into the last row of `column G` in `"Members Registration"`.

Note 1: I need this to be through a script, **NOT WITH A SIMPLE FORMULA** because if something happens to the sheet `"Members Registration"` I need the data in `sheet18` to remain there as value forever, regardless.

This script does almost what I need, but the script is copying the result twice!

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Members Registration" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Not Found") {
    var row = r.getLastRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet18");
    var target1 = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2);
    var target2 = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).copyTo(target1);
    s.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1).copyTo(target2);
  }
}
```

The result I get is this:
[image]

How do I prevent the script from copying the data more than once?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `.range` property of the event? Did you create a trigger for the function?

Comment: I don't know anything about scripts, I just took this script from another question and answer for some other things and I tried to adapt it to my needs, and yes, the trigger is set "onEdit". The trigger is not a problem, the problem is the result. 
But since I don't know how to code it, you may see things that doesn't have sense. So what do you suggest? how can I fix my script?

Comment: Ah I figured it out why it was duplicating the result. It was because the name of the function was "onEdit" and I also have added a trigger in the triggers options. 
So to fix the repetition I changed the name of the function to something else and kept the trigger in the triggers options.

Comment: if you have resolved the issue then write the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ok, Will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured it out why it was duplicating the result. It was because the name of the function was "onEdit" and I also have added a trigger in the triggers options "on edit" as well. 
So to fix the repetition I changed the name of the function to something else and kept the trigger in the triggers options. –